# Does Windows 7 run schedule auto update (at very late in night) when I SLEEP or HIBERNATE my machine?

Tags: windows-7

And does it make any difference I run windows 7 on an iMac 27"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a scheduled task in Win 7 to run a few minutes before the time it's set to check for updates. In the Conditions tab, make sure "wake the computer to run this task" is enabled. The task itself doesn't have to be anything important. You'll have to put the computer in sleep mode, not hibernate.

Comment: thx a lot, I think this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It only makes a difference if it's a VM and not bootcamp, although practically, there is no real difference for your purposes.

As for running the scheduled update, it definitely won't run during hibernation (the computer is essentially powered off with the state saved to the harddrive), and may, but probably won't run when sleeping.  If the OS isn't running, neither is update.

Comment: So is there any method that I can make sure my machine update at 3AM in the morning? Because I don't want my bandwidth occupied in business hour.